# Is there any way to "mention" a user in an API-generated comment on an item in Podio

Tags: podio

[Podio users can mention other users in comments using mentioning](https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/articles/201018938-Mentioning), but I can't find any instance of it in the Podio API documentation. Is this not technically feasible to do via API?

I've tried just manually having "@" "@<user_id>" "@" and these appear as plaintext and don't send an alert to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will want to have the "value" of the comment contain the markdown for @metnion links. Which in this case is:

```
@[Person's Name](user:userId)
```